# Typescript conditional code is running regardless of confirm() value

Tags: html, angular, typescript, if-statement, confirm

I am trying to implement a dialogue box that confirms with the user if they want to continue with an action.

```
deleteItem(index: number): void {
  let response = window.confirm("Are you sure?");
  if (response) {
      // delete item code
      this.item.splice(index,1);
      console.log("A");
  } else {
      console.log("B");
  }
}
```

When I click the deleteItem button to trigger the dialogue, it deletes the item regardless but prints the correct `console.log()` string. Can anyone help me understand why this is happening and how to correct this?

Are you sure? "Ok" => deletes the item and logs "A" in console.

Are you sure? "Cancel" => deletes the item and logs "B" in console.

Unaltered code:

```
  deleteItem(index: number): void {
    let response = window.confirm("Are you sure?");
    if (response) {
      // delete feedback in students' boolean feedback arrays
      for (var i = 0; i < this.csvRecords.length; i++) {
        if (this.students[i].feedbackBoolean[index] == true) {
          // add deduction value to student grade before delete
          var newGrade = parseFloat(this.students[i].grade) + this.feedback[index].deduction
          this.students[i].grade = newGrade.toString();
        }
        this.students[i].feedbackBoolean.splice(index,1);
      }

      // remove 1 element at index
      this.feedback.splice(index,1);

      console.log("A");
    } else {
      console.log("B");
    }
  }
```

I added the unaltered code to see if there is anything that could elicit this behavior that I might be overlooking. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please forgive me for using `javascript` to implement your example, but I found that it seems that there is no problem. Can you provide a reproducible example?

```js
const items = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

const deleteItem = (index) => {
  let response = window.confirm("Are you sure?");
  if (response) {
      // delete item code
      items.splice(index, 1);
      console.log("A");
  } else {
      console.log("B");
  }
}

deleteItem(0);
console.log(items);
```

Comment: Please see the above edit. I added the original unaltered code to see if there was any discrepancy...

Comment: Sorry I didn’t see any problem, or you tried to provide some data to run this code directly and reproduce it, or try to use `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.feedback))` after `console.log("B")` to determine whether it was deleted here, it is not ruled out because of quoting And you delete it in another location caused the problem.